# Octave/Matlab: force axes to cross at origin

Tags: matlab, coordinates, octave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crossing axis and labels in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466498/crossing-axis-and-labels-in-matlab)

This sounds like a trivial question, but I couldn't find anything online save unanswered questions.

I'm using Octave to plot functions, and I'd like the axes of my (3D) plot to cross at 0. For now, I get a kind of box-shaped coordinate system:

[image: boxed]

How would I get something like this? (taken from Wikipedia):

[image: Cartesian coordinates]

Thanks!